# JavaScript inheritance with .call(this)

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Code gotten from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model):

```
function Employee() {
    this.name = "";
    this.dept = "general";
}

function Manager() {
    Employee.call(this);
    this.reports = [];
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create( Employee.prototype );

function WorkerBee() {
    Employee.call(this);
    this.projects = [];
}

WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create( Employee.prototype );

var x = new WorkerBee();

console.log( x );
```

Output: `WorkerBee {name: "", dept: "general", projects: Array[0]}`

What effect does `Employee.call(this);` have? I know from running the code that it is necessary for inheritance to be successful. The docs for `.call()` simply state,

> method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided
>   individually.

OK so it calls the constructor `Employee()` but there is no `new` operator being used and no `return` that would return the object and it's properties. How does `Employee.call(this)` cause the child object to inherit the parent properties?

If this line is left out only the `projects` array is present as a property.

Comment: This question basically boils down to "what does `.call` do". [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: calling a constructor on an object sets in-constructor defined own properties on the object.

Comment: *"How does Employee.call(this) cause the child object to inherit the parent properties?"* It doesn't inherit anything. *"If this line is left out only the projects array is present as a property."* And what does `Employee` do? It assigns `name` and `deps` to `this`. Hence we can conclude that `Employee.call(this)` calls `Employee` and setting its `this` to the new object. Maybe this helps to understand `.call` better: `function foo() { console.log(this.name); }; foo.call({name: 'abc'}); foo.call({name: 'xyz'});`.

Comment: Hey Felix. Think I got it from your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `call` does is simply invokes function with given context `this`. In your example it means that function `Employee` is called with `this` inside of it being instance of `WorkerBee`. So what happens in this case is that when `Employee` is executed it creates and sets own properties to the `this` object which at this moment `WorkerBee`.

Check what console logs when you run the code:

```
function Employee() {
    console.log(this instanceof WorkerBee);
    this.name = "";
    this.dept = "general";
}
```

... and you will see that `this` is indeed points to the object instance of `WorkerBee`.

This pattern is used to make one constructor create own properties on the external host object (context). It's also called "borrowing constructor".

Comment: Ooh ok makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Employee.call(this);` runs the function `Employee` with `this` within the function bound to the parameter. Somewhat confusingly, the parameter is `this`. When `Employee.call(this);` is run, `this` is a reference to the `WorkerBee` object that is being created with `new`.

With `Employee.call(this);`, the `Employee` function adds additional properties to the `WorkerBee` object.

Answer (score 0):

`Employee` is just a function, like any other function. When used with the `new` operator it acts on a newly allocated object of the `Employee` "type", but that's not the only way to invoke it.

In the scenario you're referring to, it simply fills the `name` & `dept` properties of `this`.